# How to make pylint a part of setup.py test process?

Tags: python, pylint

I'm trying to add `pylint` checking of all `.py` files to the `test` process of setuptools (maybe I'm doing something wrong, please correct me). This is what I'm doing in `setup.py`:

```
class MyTest(test):
  def run_tests(self):
    import pytest
    import pylint
    if (pylint.run_pylint()):
        sys.exit(-1)
    if (pytest.main(self.test_args)):
        sys.exit(-1)
setup(
  tests_require = ['pytest', 'pylint'],
  cmdclass = {'test': MyTest},
...
```

)

When I run `python setup.py test` the output looks broken.. Am I doing it right?

Comment: Do you have an example of what you mean by broken output?

Comment: @Joe An exception without a proper pylint report. Need a full text? It's very long...

Comment: No don't need the full log, but some indication of what error you're seeing would be helpful.

Answer (score 5):

Configuration working for me:
In **setup.py**:

```
setup(
    name='...',
    setup_requires=['pytest-runner', 'pytest-pylint', ...],
    tests_require=['pytest', 'pylint']
    ...
    )
```

In **setup.cfg**:

```
[aliases]
test=pytest

[pytest]
addopts = --pylint --pylint-rcfile=...
```

Then you can run pylint just by typing:

```
python setup.py test
```

Comment: [pytest] section in setup.cfg files is deprecated, use [tool:pytest] instead

Answer (score 1):

If you are already using `py.test`, you can install [`pytest-pylint`](https://pypi.org/project/pytest-pylint/) and add this to your `setup.cfg`:

```
[tool:pytest]
addopts = --pylint
```

Comment: This requires [pytest-pylint](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pytest-pylint) is installed.

Comment: [pytest] section in setup.cfg files is deprecated, use [tool:pytest] instead